# Get data from JSON file in php

Tags: php, json, oracle

I am trying to get data from json file , parse it and add data from it to database. I am using as database, oracle.
I am getting the errors :

[image]

**This is my JSON file**

```
{
"data": {
    "gps": [
        { "location": "45.778123,24.151165"     
        },
        { "location": "45.7875116,24.1549801"               
        }
    ]
}
```

**This is my php file**

```
    <?php
        $file = 'JSONdata.json';
        $json = file_get_contents($file,0,null,null);
        $obj = json_decode($json,true);
        $data = $obj->data->gps;

        include 'connection.php';

       function insert_data($connname, $conn)
       {
          foreach ($data as $post) {
             $stmt = oci_parse($conn, "insert into GPSLOGS
                   values('".$post->location."')");
            oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
            echo "$connname inserted row without committing<br>\n";
            }
       }

        insert_data('c1', $conn);
   ?>
```

Do you know what am I doing wrong? And why it keeps getting those errors?
I also tried using another format of JSON file and parse it differently , but it keeps getting the same errors.

```
.json
      [{ "gps": "45.778123,24.151165"},{"gps": "45.7875116,24.1549801"}]

 .php
     $file = 'JSONdata.json';
     $json = file_get_contents($file,0,null,null);
     $obj = json_decode($json,true);    
       foreach($obj as $item)
       {      echo $item['gps'];}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
$data = $obj->data->gps;
```

returns data in a form of array, not object. Remove the 2nd argument from json decode and everything should work.

make it

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
$data = $obj->data->gps;
```